# In R/Shiny why using map to create tabpanels is not working?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to achieve the same result of:

```
tabsetPanel(

        # Hide the tab values.
        # Can only switch tabs by using `updateTabsetPanel()`

        tabPanel(1, "Panel 1 content"),
        tabPanel(2, "Panel 2 content"),
        tabPanel(3, "Panel 3 content")
      )
```

using this code bellow. Why it is not working?

```
 tabsetPanel(

       map(1:3,~  tabPanel(.x,title = paste0("Panel ",.x," content"))

      ))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map returns a list in a structure that tabsetPanel does not fully recognize. If you wrap everything in a call to `do.call` it should work.

```
do.call(tabsetPanel, map(1:3,~  tabPanel(.x,title = paste0("Panel ",.x," content"))))
```